# Printing a square of stars in Java 

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi I have been given a task for my course and it is to create an algorithm to make a 5 by 5 square like below:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

I've spent hours attempting to do it and read tutorials and books. It's so frustrating as I know it must be so easy if you know what you are doing. Can anyone give me any guidance as to where to start?

Comment: Homework ? you should post your code and ask for help... asking people to do it for you is not going to improve your skills.

Comment: @gareth: *Ive spent hours attempting to do it and read tutorials and books* - I'm sorry, but I can't help but think that you are lying. You need a `for`-loop and `system.out.print` - these things are among the very first things every book and tutorial covers.

Comment: Please explain the requirements more. For example, why isn't `system.out.printline("*****\n*****\n*****\n*****\n*****\n")` a valid answer (forgive me if I've remembered the syntax wrong, its been a while since I've used java)

Comment: thanks for your honesty about it being homework.  *most* of us really appreciate that.

Comment: @derobert It is `System.out.println()` :)

Comment: Next time, please post your requirement that the matrix size be input-defined as part of the question rather than as a comment to an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably know and understand how to create a "Hello World" style program in Java.
Now think - how would you go about having that same program print 5 times "Hello World"?

After that, think about how you would make it write N times "Hello World".
After *that*, think about how you would output a series of N stars.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks guys, ill get back to trying to complete it's all good fun think i just need a break and ill get back to it. I didn't want you to do my homework  just "guidance" Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you should have a variable `x` equal to the dimension (5). A `for` loop `i` that loops from `1-x`. In it a `for` loop `j` that loops from `1-x`. The `j` loops outputs `*`, or appends `*` to a string. After the `j` loop, the `i` loop does a new line.

This solution will allow for a square grid of any size.

```
int size = input;
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
   for (j=0; j<size; j++){
       // output a single "*" here
   }
   // output a new line here
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write it out to that detail, just use pseudocode: far easier to understand.

Comment: Wouldn't that be counter to `homework`? Not sure how to do so without just giving it away.

Comment: Pseudocode means code written in a language that doesn't actually compile (and may not even be formally defined) So you wouldn't writing it in java. E.g., your loop syntax might be "repeat size times" or "loop with i from 0 to size-1". Alternatively, just write it in HyperTalk, because then everyone will think its pseudocode :-P

Comment: Ok, will try that next time. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that the normal use of pseudocode is for an author to not deal with various details. For example, if I'm writing an algorithms book, I may not want to deal with e.g., all the memory management C requires (because it'd obscure the actual algorithm being implemented), or Java's love of long lines (pages are only so wide), etc. It also potentially makes the writeup more widely understandable, because "append i to the end of list l" is understood by all, but `l.push_back(i)` (C++ STL) may not be.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right, then it's about a NxN square with a given N. Your question is just about N := 5, but your comments let me assume that you've to program a more general solution.

Split the work that have to be done into more basic and smaller problems:

1. create a `String` that contains `*` N times.
2. call System.out.println() with the generated String N times

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you as well, but the professor will frown that you found the answer online and did not think of it yourself.

```
System.out.println("*****\n*****\n*****\n*****\n*****");
```

Comment: I like it, but this is clearly not what he's looking for haha

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 25;
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
      if(pos % 5 == 0){
        System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.print("*");
      pos++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you need is a console output with 5 lines of stars.
You can outpt text to console with `System.out.print()` or `System.out.println()` with the second option making a line break.

As you have to repeat the output, it is advisable to do enclose the output statement in a loop. Better in a nested loop to separate the x and the y axis.

In order to make the output modifiable - for the case you will need to output a 6x6 or 12x15 square tomorrow without any code modification, I would make the limits of the loop parametrized.

All in all, something like this :

```
public void printStartSquare(int width, int height){
    for(int i = 0; i < height;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width;j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: That would make a 6x5 square, not a 6x6

Comment: @John B No, it wouldnt, i tested it. Whats with the downvote?

Comment: The down vote was for the previous post that output "*****", I cleared it per your edit.

Comment: As other people have pointed out, posting a complete solution to `homework` as you have, is discouraged.

Comment: @John B sorry for the typo, constant delivery ;)

Comment: Definitely agree on more complicated issues, but this one looks like someone really just getting started and not knowing where to begin. Having been in such situations, I tend to help out.